# Submit data custom form in odoo 9

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I've created a custom form in CRM module (in a new item menu "Activities" ) which contains 2 fields many2one and one field type Char as it is shown bellow

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUgNm.png). But,when save button is clicked it doesn't submit data and this error message append [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGkII.png).

[image]

these are the records in **views.xml**

```
<record id="custom_crm_activity_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">activities</field>
        <field name="model">crm.activity</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree string="Activities list">
        <field name="partner_id"/>
        <field name="opportunity_id"/>
        <field name="activity_name"/>
      </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

   <record id="custom_crm_activity_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">activity form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.activity</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Activity form" version="7.0" create="true" edit="true">
          <sheet>
            <group>
            <field name="partner_id" string="Customer"/>
            <field name= "opportunity_id" string="Opportunity"/>
            <field name="activity_name" string="Activity"/>
            </group>
          </sheet>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**crm_activity.py**

```
class CrmActivity(models.Model):

    _name = 'crm.activity'
    _description = 'CRM Activity'
    _inherits = {'mail.message.subtype': 'subtype_id'}
    _rec_name = 'name'
    _order = "sequence"


    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', track_visibility='onchange', index=True,
        help="Linked partner (optional). Usually created when converting the lead.")
    opportunity_id = fields.Many2one('crm.lead', string='Opportunities', domain=[('type', '=', 'opportunity')])
    activity_name = fields.Char('Activity',default='activity name')
```

Answer (score 0):

In class CrmActivity you have declared field 'name'?
You may need to change:

```
_rec_name = 'name'
```

to:

```
_rec_name = 'activity_name'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was adding unknown columns to an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you are not declaring the field `name`, which is required (inherited from mail.message.subtype).
Add a name field to your view or rename `activity_name` to `name`.

**Comment**

Otherwise, the line

```
_rec_name = 'name'
```

Is redundant, since that is the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was adding unknown columns to an existing table.